# Extracting data from stdout_lines output

Tags: ansible

How can I split each line of the output returned from play below, into two different variables to capture the `UUID` and the `Type`, to then later use to create and populate `/etc/fstab`?

```yaml
---
- name: Get detail for fstab 
  shell: blkid | grep -v VolGrp00 | grep lv_
  register: blkids

- name: BLK UUID
    msg: "{{ blkids.stdout_lines | select ('search', item.vol_group ) | list }}"
  loop: "{{ mount_points }}"
```

Output

```yaml
TASK [linux_fstab_mount : BLK UUID] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostname123] => (item={u'mount_point': u'/tank1', u'vol_group': u'/dev/mapper/VolGrp01-lv_01'}) => {
    "msg": [
        "/dev/mapper/VolGrp01-lv_01: UUID=\"650f7950-0102-4cd8-af66-b2896bd91c3d\" TYPE=\"xfs\" "
    ]
}
ok: [hostname123] => (item={u'mount_point': u'/tank2', u'vol_group': u'/dev/mapper/VolGrp02-lv_02'}) => {
    "msg": [
        "/dev/mapper/VolGrp02-lv_02: UUID=\"8vfpsx37-03l1-0ldd-94f3-mf83mdjad13k\" TYPE=\"xfs\" "
    ]
}
```

var file

```yaml
mount_points:
  - vol_group: /dev/mapper/VolGrp01-lv_01
    mount_point: /tank1
  - vol_group: /dev/mapper/VolGrp02-lv_02
    mount_point: /tank2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"Capture the UUID and the Type (from the output of blkid) to create and populate `/etc/fstab`."***

A: Use the filter [*community.general.jc*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_conversions.html#converting-to-json) and convert the output to a list. Declare the variable

```yaml
  blkid: "{{ out.stdout|community.general.jc('blkid') }}"
```

Then the task

```yaml
    - command: blkid
      register: out
```

gives, for example

```yaml
  blkid:
  - block_size: '512'
    device: /dev/sda1
    partlabel: EFI System Partition
    partuuid: c9c9cb77-3fa8-46a0-995c-1584f54ad134
    type: vfat
    uuid: 2F0B-293A
  - block_size: '512'
    device: /dev/sda2
    partuuid: 08b42891-2ebf-4367-8d09-7c25ae7b0790
    type: xfs
    uuid: 974052e6-e99e-4259-8830-f842da183489
  - device: /dev/sda3
    ...
```

Let's say you'd like to use *uuid* in *fstab* instead of the device. Create a  dictionary for this purpose

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        device_uuid: "{{ blkid|selectattr('uuid', 'defined')|
                               items2dict(key_name='device', value_name='uuid') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  device_uuid:
    /dev/mapper/cl-root: 2cb4d983-108f-40f3-bc22-8afae8edc80a
    /dev/mapper/cl-swap: a9c490a5-cba6-4c7d-a755-4adbfd39602a
    /dev/sda1: 2F0B-293A
    /dev/sda2: 974052e6-e99e-4259-8830-f842da183489
    /dev/sda3: O0ScB1-uxAt-huqi-whF1-4Ztv-pbdT-oL70xc
```

Given the list of the mount points

```yaml
  mount_points:
    - mount_point: /boot
      device: /dev/sda2
      fstype: xfs
      opts: defaults
    - mount_point: /boot/efi
      device: /dev/sda1
      fstype: vfat
      opts: 'umask=0077,shortname=winnt'
      passno: 2
```

Use the module [*ansible.posix.mount*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/mount_module.html#ansible-posix-mount-module-control-active-and-configured-mount-points) to mount the filesystems and to add or update the entries in the *fstab*

```yaml
    - ansible.posix.mount:
        src: "UUID={{ device_uuid[item.device] }}"
        path: "{{ item.mount_point }}"
        fstype: "{{ item.fstype|d(omit) }}"
        opts: "{{ item.opts|d(omit) }}"
        dump: "{{ item.dump|d(omit) }}"
        passno: "{{ item.passno|d(omit) }}"
        state: "{{ item.state|d('present') }}"
        backup: true
      loop: "{{ mount_points }}"
      when: not dry_run|d(false)|bool
```

gives

```bash
[root@test_24 etc]# cat /etc/fstab

 ...

UUID=974052e6-e99e-4259-8830-f842da183489 /boot xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=2F0B-293A          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2

 ...
```

---

Notes

1. Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_24

  vars:

    mount_points:
      - mount_point: /boot
        device: /dev/sda2
        fstype: xfs
        opts: defaults
      - mount_point: /boot/efi
        device: /dev/sda1
        fstype: vfat
        opts: 'umask=0077,shortname=winnt'
        passno: 2
          
    blkid: "{{ out.stdout|community.general.jc('blkid') }}"

  tasks:

    - block:
        - command: blkid
          register: out
        - debug:
            var: blkid
        - set_fact:
            device_uuid: "{{ blkid|selectattr('uuid', 'defined')|
                                   items2dict(key_name='device', value_name='uuid') }}"
            cacheable: true
        - debug:
            var: device_uuid
      when: dry_run|d(false)|bool

    - debug:
        msg: |
          path: {{ item.mount_point }}
          src:  UUID={{ device_uuid[item.device] }}
      loop: "{{ mount_points }}"

    - ansible.posix.mount:
        src: "UUID={{ device_uuid[item.device] }}"
        path: "{{ item.mount_point }}"
        fstype: "{{ item.fstype|d(omit) }}"
        opts: "{{ item.opts|d(omit) }}"
        dump: "{{ item.dump|d(omit) }}"
        passno: "{{ item.passno|d(omit) }}"
        state: "{{ item.state|d('present') }}"
        backup: true
      loop: "{{ mount_points }}"
      when: not dry_run|d(false)|bool
```

2. Enable cache. For example,

```ini
shell> grep fact_caching ansible.cfg
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible_cache
fact_caching_prefix = ansible_facts_
fact_caching_timeout = 86400
```

This will help you to cache the data and use it when running the playbook in `--check --diff` mode

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e dry_run=true

PLAY [test_24] *******************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_24]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24] => 
  blkid:
  - block_size: '512'
    device: /dev/sda1
    partlabel: EFI System Partition
    partuuid: c9c9cb77-3fa8-46a0-995c-1584f54ad134
    type: vfat
    uuid: 2F0B-293A
  - block_size: '512'
    device: /dev/sda2
    partuuid: 08b42891-2ebf-4367-8d09-7c25ae7b0790
    type: xfs
    uuid: 974052e6-e99e-4259-8830-f842da183489
  - device: /dev/sda3
    partuuid: 1f11c8fe-337f-0340-9506-03a2684462cd
    type: LVM2_member
    uuid: O0ScB1-uxAt-huqi-whF1-4Ztv-pbdT-oL70xc
  - block_size: '512'
    device: /dev/mapper/cl-root
    type: xfs
    uuid: 2cb4d983-108f-40f3-bc22-8afae8edc80a
  - device: /dev/mapper/cl-swap
    type: swap
    uuid: a9c490a5-cba6-4c7d-a755-4adbfd39602a

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [test_24]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24] => 
  device_uuid:
    /dev/mapper/cl-root: 2cb4d983-108f-40f3-bc22-8afae8edc80a
    /dev/mapper/cl-swap: a9c490a5-cba6-4c7d-a755-4adbfd39602a
    /dev/sda1: 2F0B-293A
    /dev/sda2: 974052e6-e99e-4259-8830-f842da183489
    /dev/sda3: O0ScB1-uxAt-huqi-whF1-4Ztv-pbdT-oL70xc

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24] => (item={'mount_point': '/boot', 'device': '/dev/sda2', 'fstype': 'xfs', 'opts': 'defaults'}) => 
  msg: |-
    path: /boot
    src:  UUID=974052e6-e99e-4259-8830-f842da183489
ok: [test_24] => (item={'mount_point': '/boot/efi', 'device': '/dev/sda1', 'fstype': 'vfat', 'opts': 'umask=0077,shortname=winnt', 'passno': 2}) => 
  msg: |-
    path: /boot/efi
    src:  UUID=2F0B-293A

TASK [ansible.posix.mount] *******************************************************************
skipping: [test_24] => (item={'mount_point': '/boot', 'device': '/dev/sda2', 'fstype': 'xfs', 'opts': 'defaults'}) 
skipping: [test_24] => (item={'mount_point': '/boot/efi', 'device': '/dev/sda1', 'fstype': 'vfat', 'opts': 'umask=0077,shortname=winnt', 'passno': 2}) 

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_24: ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Run the playbook in `--check --diff` mode

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e dry_run=false -CD

PLAY [test_24] *******************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
skipping: [test_24]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [test_24]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
skipping: [test_24]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [test_24]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24] => (item={'mount_point': '/boot', 'device': '/dev/sda2', 'fstype': 'xfs', 'opts': 'defaults'}) => 
  msg: |-
    path: /boot
    src:  UUID=974052e6-e99e-4259-8830-f842da183489
ok: [test_24] => (item={'mount_point': '/boot/efi', 'device': '/dev/sda1', 'fstype': 'vfat', 'opts': 'umask=0077,shortname=winnt', 'passno': 2}) => 
  msg: |-
    path: /boot/efi
    src:  UUID=2F0B-293A

TASK [ansible.posix.mount] *******************************************************************
ok: [test_24] => (item={'mount_point': '/boot', 'device': '/dev/sda2', 'fstype': 'xfs', 'opts': 'defaults'})
ok: [test_24] => (item={'mount_point': '/boot/efi', 'device': '/dev/sda1', 'fstype': 'vfat', 'opts': 'umask=0077,shortname=winnt', 'passno': 2})

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_24: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=4    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the necessary result there are different ways possible. Since I have a similar use case in my environment I like to share parts of my solution approach.

**Pre-processing or Data cleansing**

According [`man blkid`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid) there is the option `-s` available to show only specific information, in example the UUID.

```yaml
- name: "Get block ID for {{ mount_points[0].vol_group  }}"
  shell: 
    cmd: "blkid -s UUID -o value {{ mount_points[0].vol_group }}"
  register: BLKID

- name: Show result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ BLKID }}"
```

in your case resulting into an output of just

```
650f7950-0102-4cd8-af66-b2896bd91c3d
```

Furthermore there are queries possible like

```bash
blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/mapper/VolGrp0[1,2]*
```

in your case resulting into a list of

```bash
650f7950-0102-4cd8-af66-b2896bd91c3d
8vfpsx37-03l1-0ldd-94f3-mf83mdjad13k
```

or even

```bash
blkid -s UUID -s TYPE -o value /dev/mapper/VolGrp0[1,2]*
```

This is simpler, easier to maintain and no need for `grep`, `select('search', ...)`, etc.

---

**How to extract data from `stdout_lines` output?**"

A more general approach would be to use

- the [`jc` - JSON Convert `blkid` command output parser `jc.parser.blkid`](https://kellyjonbrazil.github.io/jc/docs/parsers/blkid.html) before [registering the result](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables)
- or the Ansible Community module equivalent [`jc` filter – Convert output of many shell commands and file-types to JSON](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/community/general/jc_filter.html) which process the data afterwards as requested

and as [shown in the other answer by Vladimir Botka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74905447/6771046).